# Why Implicitly unwrapped optional was not assigned?

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

In following code, why 5 is not assigned to "somevar" ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var somevar : Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        somevar! = Int(5) // why 5 is not assigned to somevar here
    }
}
```

**Background:**

`somevar` is declared as an optional variable which means if this variable is nil then command using this variable will be ignored.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var somevar : Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        somevar? = 5 // this command will be ignored bcz somevar is nil
    }
}
```

To forcefully execute the command on our own risk we use "Implicitly unwrapped optional" so that we are sure that command will be executed, in that case following line is executed

```
somevar! = 5
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When this line is executed, why "5" is not assigned to "somevar" instead a fatal error occurs?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var somevar : Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        somevar! = 5
    }
}
```

Comment: the correct way to assign a value to a var is `somevar = 5` not `somevar? = 5`

Answer (score 2):

When we do `something!` (emphasis on the **!** mark), we are "*force reading*" (*force unwrapping*) an optional.

That is to say that the above code tries to read `something` before assigning it a new value.
Since `something` is `nil`, the code explodes.

To illustrate:

```
var somevar: Int?

print(somevar!)
// Code explodes! 

print(somevar)
// Output is "nil"

somevar = 5

print(somevar!)
// Output is "5"

print(somevar)
// Output is "Optional(5)"
```

As @LeoDabus stated, this is covered in [Apple's awesome Swift book](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11).
(BTW a really good book! ❤️)

Comment: @LeoDabus doesn't make any difference considering the question, but I get your point and changed my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Also "force reading" (force unwrapping) = Gold! :)  (mentioning that clarified a lot)
Going through the book

Answer (score 0):

To give some color on what `somevar? = 5` is doing.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

// In swift you have to unwrap an optional before you can do anything with it
var x: Int? = 1
var y: Int? = 2

// So you can't do this
//var z = x + y

// You have to do this
if let x = x,
    let y = y {
    // Here x and y are no longer of the type Int? they are of the type Int
    var z = x + y
}

// You don't have to name them the same
if let someX = x,
    let someY = y {
    // Here x and y are no longer of the type Int? they are of the type Int
    var z = someX + someY
}

// This can be a pain sometimes if you want to "do nothing" in the nil case, or want to unwrap something multiple "levels"
// of optionals deep. For example:

struct Pet {
    let name: String
}

struct Person {
    let pet: Pet?
}

var person: Person? = Person(pet: Pet(name: "Rex"))

// To get the person's pet's name we have to unwrap a few things
if let person = person,
    let pet = person.pet {
    print("The pet's name is \(pet.name)")
}

// We can do this a little easier by using "Optional Chaining"
if let name = person?.pet?.name {
    print("The pet's name is \(name)")
}

// So here's where your problem comes in
var number: Int? = nil

// This is "optional chaining" the assignment of 5 to number. But, because number is current nil the assignment won't happen.
number? = 5

// However
number = 5

// Now the number is 5

number? = 10

// Now the number is 10, because the optional chaining succeded because number was not nil. All this being said, I've never
// seen someone use x? = 5 in production code, and I can't think of a reason to do that. Just do x = 5 like the other
// answers have said.
```

TL;DR, `somevar? = 5` is using Optional Chaining to only set `somevar` to `5` if it is not `nil`.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew for the explanation.